# Calling custom jQuery plugin inside other jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's `.popover` jQuery plugin. I am writing my own jQuery plugin that utilizes `.popover`, but the console says that `this` "has no method 'popover'." Here's my code:

```
$.fn.mypopover = function(msg){
    this.click(function(){
        this.popover({title:"Static title",content:msg,trigger:'manual'}).popover('show');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `$.fn.popover` function, `this` is the jQuery object that `popover()` was called on.  However, inside the callback to `this.click()`, `this` is the element that triggered the click event.  Every time you are inside another `function`, `this` will be different (based on how the function is called).

You need to do `$(this).popover()` inside the click event.

```
$.fn.mypopover = function(msg){
    // "this" is a jQuery object
    this.click(function(){
        // "this" is a DOM element
        $(this).popover({title:"Static title",content:msg,trigger:'manual'}).popover('show');
    });
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I set `ths = $(this);` on the first line inside the anonymous function. Thanks!